# Linking libbz2.dll under windows (64-bit)

Tags: c, windows, gcc, linker, 64-bit

I'm trying to use `BZ2_bzBuffToBuffDecompress()` provided by bzlib.h from bzip.org

My OS is windows 8 64-bit.
I'm using Dev-C++ 5.6.2 and MingW64.

I created a new C project, included "bzip2-1.0.6/bzlib.h" and added the linker `-lbz2`

Then I built libbz2.dll using Visual studio 2013.

The first time, I built it using the Win32 platform option, witch gave me (while compiling my C program)

> skipping incompatible .../bzip2-1.0.6/libbz2.dll when searching for
>   -lbz2

The second time, I built it using the x64 platform option, witch gave me

> undefined reference to BZ2_bzBuffToBuffDecompress

Is there any way to solve this?

**UPDATE**

I tried the libraries from Cygwin64 (libbz2.a, libbz2.dll.a, libbz2-2.dll) but each one gave the first error message.

**UPDATE 2**

I ended up using MinGW (32-bit) with libbz2-2.dll